# Movement based on direction of car?

Tags: libgdx, rotation, direction

I'm currently making a simple racing game in libGDX. I am stuck on figuring out how to move my car object based on its direction. So far I have a class PlayerCar.java as shown below:

```
public class PlayerCar {

    private Vector2 position, velocity;
    private int width, height;
    private float rotation;
    private Rectangle boundingBox;

    public PlayerCar(float x, float y, int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        position = new Vector2(x, y);
        rotation = 0;
        velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        boundingBox = new Rectangle();
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));
        boundingBox.set(position.x, position.y, width, height);
    }

    public void stop() {
        velocity.x = 0;
        velocity.y = 0;
    }

    //Code to deal with movement here

}
```

I'm stuck because in all the other 2d games I have developed the movement directions have always stayed the same.Can someone please tell me what is an efficient way to achieve this direction-based movement?

Answer (score 0):

Enter trigonometry!

Getting a directional vector from an angle is very easy:

```
x = cos(angle)
y = sin(angle)
```

Where angle is the rotation in radians.

Then you multiply this with the velocity and add it to the position.

Answer (score 0):

Store the speed as a scalar then rotate a vector by the direction (in degrees) by using the `rotate` method on the `Vector2` class:

```
public void update(float delta) {   
Vector2 v = new Vector2().rotate (direction).scl(speed).scl(delta);     
position.add(v);
    boundingBox.set(position.x, position.y, width, height);
}
```

Note that for performance reasons you probably dont want to new up a new `Vector2` every tick.